# html-Top menu and body conflicted

Tags: html, css

I have met a problem on my html which is this

CSS:

```
.fixedmenu {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:rgb(153,0,51);
    position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    font-size:2em;
}

#bodybox {           
    border:0px;
    width:80%;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    background:red;
}
```

and this is  my code in body

```
<div class="fixedmenu">
    <div style="float: left;color:white;padding:0.5% 0% 0.5% 3%;">YggDrasil ||</div>
    <div style="float: right;color:white;padding:0.5% 3% 0.5% 0%;"> || Login</div>
    <div style="margin:0 auto; width:300px;color:white;padding:0.5% 0% 0.5% 0%;"> Welcome to YggDrasil. </div>
</div>
```

It is still working well until this code

```
<div id="bodybox"> 
    hi  
</div>
```

after putting this one the margin of my top menu will move to right. How to solve it?

Comment: and the word "hi" is not appearing

Comment: I cannot reproduce the bug please provide a working code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `margin: 0;` on your `body` and `.fixedmenu` and set the `position:relative;` on both your `.fixedmenu` and `#bodybox`. This way everything will fit nicely on your window and you'll be able to see the new div after the menu. I've also change the width on the menu to `width: 100vw;`.

```
<body>
    <div class="fixedmenu">
        <div style="float: left;color:white;padding:0.5% 0% 0.5% 3%;">YggDrasil ||</div>
        <div style="float: right;color:white;padding:0.5% 3% 0.5% 0%;"> || Login</div>
        <div style="margin:0 auto; width:300px;color:white;padding:0.5% 0% 0.5% 0%;"> Welcome to YggDrasil. </div>

    </div>
    <div id="bodybox"> hi</div> 

</body>
```

Styles applied:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
.fixedmenu {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(153, 0, 51);
    position: fixed;
    /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0;
    /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
    width: 100vw;
    /* Full width */
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
}

#bodybox {
    border: 0px;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: red;
    position:relative;
}
```

My result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it worked! Because I'm working on pspad so sometimes the chrome will display different thing from the preview web of pspad. That really makes me mad.So now finally got it worked..

Comment: No problem ^^ If you still have another problem then you should create a new question. Happy to help!

Comment: I have another problem.When I trying to shrinking my window.My text goes together and shrink with the window. I have tried the position fixed but it does't work. How can I do with that?